# Need to extract text field alone from JSON

Tags: c#, json

Could anybody help me to extract only the text field from the below JSON (response from my program) using c#

```
[{"unMeta":{}},[{"t":"Plain","c":[{"t":"Str","c":"{\"language\":\"en\",\"textAngle\":0.0,\"orientation\":\"Up\",\"regions\":[{\"boundingBox\":\"7,7,476,264\",\"lines\":
[{\"boundingBox\":\"7,7,476,58\",\"words\":
[{\"boundingBox\":\"7,7,42,44\",\"text\":\"If\"},{\"boundingBox\":\"62,16,283,49\",\"text\":\"computers\"},{\"boundingBox\":\"361,9,122,45\",\"text\":\"can't\"}]},
{\"boundingBox\":\"7,77,451,57\",\"words\":
[{\"boundingBox\":\"7,77,149,56\",\"text\":\"adapt\"},{\"boundingBox\":\"172,77,155,57\",\"text\":\"easily,\"},{\"boundingBox\":\"338,79,120,43\",\"text\":\"then\"}]},
{\"boundingBox\":\"8,146,460,57\",\"words\":
[{\"boundingBox\":\"8,146,178,56\",\"text\":\"maybe\"},{\"boundingBox\":\"201,147,82,44\",\"text\":\"the\"},{\"boundingBox\":\"299,148,169,55\",\"text\":\"people\"}]},
{\"boundingBox\":\"7,214,414,57\",\"words\":
[{\"boundingBox\":\"7,214,145,57\",\"text\":\"using\"},{\"boundingBox\":\"166,216,137,43\",\"text\":\"them\"},{\"boundingBox\":\"318,231,103,29\",\"text\":\"can.\"}]}]}]}"}]}]]
```

I am using the below code but response .regions throws error* i need to extract only the text field from the above JSON. I need to loop through the nodes

```
static async Task readJsonOutput(string response)
    {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        if (response != null && **response.Regions** != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in response.Regions)
            {
                foreach (var line in item.Lines)
                {
                    foreach (var word in line.Words)
                    {
                        stringBuilder.Append(word.Text);
                        stringBuilder.Append(" ");
                    }
                    stringBuilder.AppendLine();
                }
                stringBuilder.AppendLine();
            }
        }    
        string result = stringBuilder.ToString();
        //return stringBuilder.ToString();
    }
}

public class Region
{
    public string BoundingBox { get; set; }
    public List<Line> Lines { get; set; }
}

public class Line
{
    public string BoundingBox { get; set; }
    public List<Word> Words { get; set; }
}   
public class Word
{
    public string BoundingBox { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Please format your code part properly

Comment: Why don't you try deserialising the object if you have defined type using JSONConvert ? Something like this `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);`

Comment: start with extracting only one of the outermost objects, then in another c# statement another extraction. That way you can easily use the debugger

Answer (score 2):

Part of the problem is the JSON is double serialized.  So you need to parse it, then get the "real" JSON from innermost `c` property and parse that part a second time.  Then you can extract the `text` properties from there.

Using Json.Net's [LINQ-to-JSON](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm) API, you can do it like this:

```
var innerJson = (string)JToken.Parse(json).SelectTokens("$..c").Last();
var words = JToken.Parse(innerJson).SelectTokens("$..text").Select(t => (string)t);
var text = string.Join(" ", words);
```

Demo here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/UvBRqv